# mask doesn't work if it is assigned to a layer which is a sublayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

got a _imageView which is properly added and located

if a layer is assigned to _imageView.layer.mask, it worked:

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

[maskLayer setPath:maskPath;

[maskLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(50, 50)]

[_imageViewLayer setMask:maskLayer];
```

now the mask blocks content outside its path

however,if a layer is assigned to one of _imageView.layer.sublayers, it blocks everything:

```
_imageViewLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

CGPathRef circlePath = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100), nil);

[_imageViewLayer setPath: circlePath];

[_imageViewLayer setPosition: CGPoinMake(50, 50)];

CGPathRelease(circlePath);

[_imageViewLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];

[[_imageView layer] addSublayer:_imageViewLayer];


CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

CGPathRef maskPath = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10), nil);

[maskLayer setPath:maskPath];

CGPathRelease(maskPath);

[maskLayer setPosition: CGPoinMake(50, 50)];

[_imageViewLayer setMask: maskLayer];
```

if i remove the maskLayer, i can see a red circle on _imageView

could anyone give me a hint, or it's just a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple:

```
/* A layer whose alpha channel is used as a mask to select between the
 * layer's background and the result of compositing the layer's
 * contents with its filtered background. Defaults to nil. When used as
 * a mask the layer's `compositingFilter' and `backgroundFilters'
 * properties are ignored. When setting the mask to a new layer, the
 * new layer must have a nil superlayer, otherwise the behavior is
 * undefined. Nested masks (mask layers with their own masks) are
 * unsupported. */

@property(nullable, strong) CALayer *mask;
```

"When setting the mask to a new layer, the new layer must have a nil superlayer, otherwise the behavior is undefined. "

Your `_imageViewLayer` has already had a superlayer `[_imageView layer]` when you are setting `maskLayer` to `_imageViewLayer` as a mask.